# Register MPEG-4 as Dragged Type using pyobjc on macos

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyobjc, uti

I'm trying to register MPEG-4 as a dragged type using pyobjc with the specific goal of being able to drag voice memos directly out of the app into my own python application.

I tried registering UTI types "public.audio", "public.mpeg-4-audio", NSPasteboard.URLType and NSPasteboard.fileURLType as per Apples [Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259). However dropping a file on my program always resulted in the same error: "The document x could not be opened. Python cannot open files in the 'Apple MPEG-4 audio' format.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```py
from AppKit import NSApplication, NSObject, NSDragOperationCopy, NSWindow, NSView, NSPasteboard, NSPasteboard
from PyObjCTools import AppHelper

class DropView(NSView):
    def initWithFrame_(self, frame):
        self = super(DropView, self).initWithFrame_(frame)
        if self:
            self.registerForDraggedTypes_(["public.audio", "public.mpeg-4-audio", NSPasteboard.URLType, NSPasteboard.fileURLType])
        return self

    def draggingEntered_(self, sender):
        pboard = sender.draggingPasteboard()
        return NSDragOperationCopy

    def performDragOperation_(self, sender):
        pboard = sender.draggingPasteboard()
        print(pboard)
        return True

class AppDelegate(NSObject):
    def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, notification):
        self.window = NSWindow.alloc().initWithContentRect_styleMask_backing_defer_(((100, 100), (400, 300)), 1 << 1 | 1 << 10, 2, False)
        self.window.setTitle_("Drag-and-Drop Example")

        drop_view = DropView.alloc().initWithFrame_(((0, 0), (400, 300)))
        self.window.contentView().addSubview_(drop_view)

        self.window.makeKeyAndOrderFront_(None)

def run_app():
    app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
    delegate = AppDelegate.alloc().init()
    app.setDelegate_(delegate)

    AppHelper.runEventLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_app()
```

Comment: Here is link. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttypempeg4audio

Comment: @toyotaSupra As it states, the correct type should be "public.mpeg-4-audio" however it doesn't remove the error message.